# How to use t-if condition in qweb to detect a field contains a string?

Tags: conditional-statements, qweb

I'm working in Odoo 8.

In a qweb report, does it exist a operator to detect if a field contains a particular string?

Example :

```
<div t-if="p.name **contains** 'SUM'">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

Thanks to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'in' operator to check whether field contains a particular string or not.

```
<div t-if="'SUM' in p.name">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

**p.name == 'SUM'** will check exact **name = SUM**, to check portion of string in field **'in'** operator is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Perfect!

Comment: This is not working in the moment when I posted this comment (odoo 12.0).